# Vertex Paiting slightly hidden parts of the mesh

Tags: vertex-paint

I'm Vertex Painting an object that is has small depressions and bumps. When I make a stroke from some angle, there seem to be a bunch of vertices that don't receive the stroke.

In the following image, I painted a stroke in the top-right panel. It looks a smooth swath was painted, but as can be seen from the other views, many vertices were missed.

[image]

Is it possible to configure the brush to avoid missing vertices in a situation like this?

p.s. Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm painting with exact colours (i.e. I set the brush curve shape to constant, to be sure that the colour on my brush is the colour that actually makes it on the mesh).

Answer (score 2):

I think that is not possible to configure the vertex paint brush with the options provided by Blender at this time (2.75a) without scripting yourself the tool you need.

The vertex brush simply cannot "see" the face, probably because it's normal is not facing the brush projection enough...or something like that...
I'm not a coder as you might have guessed, but I can suggest to you two alternatives workflows:

**1-Texture paint-->Vertex Color**

- UV unwrap your model
- Create a texture
- Paint your colors on the texture
- Install and use the Bake Uv-Texture to Vertex colors add-on

By painting with the texture tools you'll be able to access the "Normal threshold" options that make you able to define a custom range for your brush

[image]

Than you can extract color info from the texture map through the add-on and bake them to vertex color

*Result*:

[image]

**2 - Edit mode, expand and contract selection**

- Go to Edit mode
- Select faces
- Ctrl+"+" to expand till filling holes
- Ctrl+"-" to reduce selection to the initial size
- Go to Vertex paint, set "face selection masking" on to work only on
  the selected faces
- Shift+"k" to paint the brush color on the active faces

This works only if you are using solid colours, without blending ramps on the border or other features that the vertex paint is able to achieve.

And of course you have to iterate the process for every different colour (and without the possibility to see what you have done before).

Before expanding and contracting selection:

[image]

After:

[image]

Setting color to selected faces in edit mode:

[image]